# How to wait on multiple MPSC channels with different priorities to create an ordered queue?

Tags: rust, channel

I have a single thread that waits on a channel:

```
for msg in rx {}
```

I would like to wait on two channels, one with high priority and one with low priority. The for loop should take items from the high queue before looking at the low queue.

Issues I'm having:

- I can either block on one channel, or use `try_recv` on both in a loop which is inefficient.
- [`Select`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.9.0/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Select.html) for MPSC channels is ["dubious"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27800).
- I cannot use [crossbeam_channel](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam-channel) because I'd like to clear the high queue first before taking from the low queue, but [`select!`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam-channel/0.3.9/crossbeam_channel/macro.select.html) states:

  > If multiple operations are ready at the same time, a random one among them is selected

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Thanks, but Id like to clear the high queue first before taking from the low queue: `If multiple operations are ready at the same time, a random one among them is selected`. I did see that page briefly, but was also interested in other alternatives that I may not have considered as Im new to Rust. Would a binary heap work? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/binary_heap/

Comment: Have you seen [crossbeam-channel: Select with priorities?](https://github.com/crossbeam-rs/crossbeam/issues/288)

Comment: I see, does look useful. So I would use `high.try_recv` when when I get a message from the low queue, and make sure `high.len == 0` before then processing the low items? I think it could work, thanks.